# Trying to get the euro symbol using chr(128)

Tags: php, euro, chr

I expected this code:

```
define('EURO_SIMBOLO', chr(128));
$euro = EURO_SIMBOLO;
var_dump($euro);
```

to show the `€` symbol, but it doesn't. Why does this happen?

Comment: This depends on the character set you are using. What encoding are your pages in?

Comment: Hi, Pekka, how to know the encoding of my pages?

Comment: @user the browser's "encoding" or "character set" menu will have a check mark on the encoding it is currently using.

Comment: The Euro symbol does not exist in **Latin-1**. It has an representation in ISO-8859-15 (Latin-9) however, and the charcode would be `\xA4` or `164` then.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to go with Unicode, UTF-8 more specifically, which I prefer because of its flexibility, you can output the Euro sign using:

```
echo "\xE2\x82\xAc"; // 3 bytes-long multibyte character
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of € (alt + 0128)

switch your euro code to

```
&euro;
```

Answer (score 2):

This will only work if you're using a [125x code page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#Windows_.28ANSI.29_code_pages). The fact is that the euro character is not included in **all** extended ASCII character sets (introduced in ISO/IEC 8859-15), however it does have a de-facto Unicode character.

If this is simply for displaying in a browser, consider using either `'&#8364;'` or `'&euro;'`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using such a character set with the euro-symbol you’re most likely using iso-8859-15 in which the '€' character is defined at position 164.
So you might have more luck if you replace 128 by 164, although this won’t help you in utf-8 environments in which the previous answer might be more suited.

Answer (score 0):

In the CP1252 encoding of € has the code 128;
In ISO-8859-15 the code is 164;
Macintosh Roman is 219;

The euro sign is a part of the ASCII. Look that http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: You spoke ASCII character set (0 to 255), its include the extended table (128 to 255) added before 1986. The euro sign is first character of extended table (128)